# How to find out when azure snapshot is finished creating

Tags: javascript, azure, virtual-machine

I'm taking a snapshot of a disk on azure. I'm using the Node SDK. When I issue the command to take a snapshot, within a few seconds I get the response back. I'll paste the output below.

The thing is, the provisioning state always shows `Succeeded` even though the snapshot is obviously not finished being created yet. And it does not yet show in the dashboard.

If I use the `snapshot.list` the method, it also says `Succeeded` for this snapshot.

How can I query to find out when the snapshot is actually finished being created?

```
{ id:
     '/subscriptions/1a6c4c11-6729-48fb-8e76-06c6281bb6f1/resourceGroups/RGOUP1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/snapCostTest',
    name: 'snapCostTest',
    type: 'Microsoft.Compute/snapshots',
    location: 'westus',
    sku: { name: 'Standard_LRS', tier: 'Standard' },
    timeCreated: 2019-08-16T00:51:04.099Z,
    osType: 'Windows',
    hyperVGeneration: 'V1',
    creationData:
     { createOption: 'Copy',
       sourceResourceId:
        '/subscriptions/1a6c4c11-6729-48fb-8e76-06c6281bb6f1/resourceGroups/RGOUP1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/vm1_OsDisk_1_502b5534fe4b4f288d19e127c457d652' },
    diskSizeGB: 127,
    provisioningState: 'Succeeded' }
```

I would have thought the `provisioningState` would show something like `Creating` while the snapshot is being created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the rest API below to get detailed information of your disks :

```
GET https://management.azure.com/<YOUR DISK ID>?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Only `properties.provisioningState` in response value turned "Succeeded" , the disk will shows up on portal dashboard.